# Javascript to analyze a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, google-chrome-extension

So I figured I'd get a little bit of Javascript practice and work on my first Google Chrome extension. I'm making an extension that, when the user clicks the "Like" button on Facebook, if the post they click on is older than a certain threshold, then it prompts them to make sure they indeed meant to click "Like" on the post (to prevent accidental likes when stalking).

I have basic functionality down where if the user clicks like it prompts them to make sure they meant to hit like, and if they didn't meant to, they can cancel the like at that point. However, now I'm trying to add detection of whether a post is of a certain age or not, to only prompt when the post is old.

My source for what I have right now is located here:
https://github.com/mathur/StalkingCondom

Essentially, Facebook stores this data in a timestamp, and I want to know how to access the timestamp just from the post where the user is currently "liking" and not any of the other timestamps on the page.

Below is my code that runs when the document is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".UFILikeLink" ).click(function(e) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to like this?")) {
            // like was intended, continue with usual behavior
        }
        else {
            // like was not intended, lets stop that like!
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

The timestamps are stored between abbr tags like below:

```
<abbr data-utime="1421210082" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">10 mins</abbr>`
```

Every post has its own div with certain unique ID.

Basically I need to wrap the entire UFILikeLink click function in an if statement where if the date is older than a certain date then execute the click function right? How would I make it so the Javascript finds the timestamp only within that one unique div?

Is anyone willing to point me in the right direction? Is this even feasibly possible? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: If you have a specific question about a specific issue, post the code here instead of linking to it off site. Also, we don't need to know your whole back story. Sounds like you want to extract the time from a timestamp. Is that right? It's getting lost in all your verbiage. If that's all you need, then ask about that, show what data you're talking about and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I tried to clarify it - does that help? thanks for giving feedback!

Comment: I'm not sure what the relationship is between your JavaScript and the page. But where are you having trouble? Are you unable to select the `abbr` element? Or are you unable to get the value of the `data-utime`? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: **Facebook's timeline gets updated via AJAX requests every time you reach the bottom**, so adding a listener to `$(".UFILikeLink")` will only work on the first few links (loaded at the beginning). **If you want it to work for ALL the links, you'll have to add a listener to the `<body>` element**.

So you will use `addEventListener('click', func(){...}, true)` to add a listener for the click event, and set `useCapture=true` (last argument). With `useCapture` set as `true` you can prevent the events before they reach the target element and stop them when necessary. Then, inside the event listener you will check if the clicked element has class `UFILikeButton`, and, if so, continue.

Now, before writing down anything, you need to make some corrections considering the following facts:

1. The "Like" text that the user clicks is actually a `<span>`, and does not have the class "UFILikeLink", but **its parent does**. Here is the structure of a like link:

   ```
   <a class="UFILikeLink" href="#" role="button" aria-live="polite" title="Like this" ...>
       <span data-reactid=".27.1">Like</span>
   </a>
   ```
2. You don't exactly know where the `<abbr>` element is located, so **you'll need to search for i**t: using `.parents(".userContentWrapper")` you'll find the post body container, which contains the `<abbr>` element, then using `.find("abbr")` you'll finally get to it. Here is the full code:

   ```
   var timestamp = +$(e.target).parents(".userContentWrapper").find("abbr").attr("data-utime");
   ```

   <sup>*The + (plus) converts the string to a number</sup>
3. **If the user clicks on "Unlike" instead of "Like", you should not display the prompt**, so it is useful to check for the text contained inside the clicked element, like this:

   ```
   $(e.target).text() == 'Unlike';
   ```
4. **Facebook timestamps are in seconds**, but JavaScript timestamps are in milliseconds. To compare them you have either to multiply the first one or divide the second one by 1000.

Here is the final code, to make things easier I created `likeLink`, which is the link with class "UFILikeLink", and `likeSpan`, which represents the text contained in the link (the one the user really clicks).

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var likeLink = $(e.target.parentElement),
        likeSpan = $(e.target),
        timestamp, oldTimestamp;

    // If the clicked element is not the Like button, just stop the function
    if (!likeLink.hasClass("UFILikeLink")) return;

    // If the users clicks to UNLIKE, you don't need to check
    if (likeSpan.text() == 'Unlike') return;

    timestamp = +likeLink.parents(".userContentWrapper").find("abbr").attr("data-utime");

    // Set a limit of one month ago (2592000 seconds = 30 days)
    oldTimestamp = +new Date()/1000 - 2592000;

    // If the post is older than one month...
    if (timestamp < oldTimestamp && !confirm("Are you sure you want to like this?")) {
        // like was not intended, lets stop that like!
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, true);
```

The above code will prompt the "Are you sure?" message for posts older than one month. You can edit the check variable to set it to older or newer posts.

Comment: Just for the record: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: @Xan since that jQuery objects haven't got datasets, I found it easier to do `$el.attr('data-x')` rather than `$el[0].dataset.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to the parent div however you want. If you know the Id for the div, that's an option. If they're all inside a container, maybe you can get it by ID and iterate over its children. You'd have to provide the markup to get a more specific answer on that part. Once you have that reference to the div, you can get the child element by tag name (assuming there's only one abbr tag inside, or at least there's are recognizable pattern). Here's an example of the call you could make to do it.

```
document.getElementById('parentDivId').getElementsByTagName('abbr')[0].getAttribute('data-utime');
```

Breaking that out into parts,

- document.getElementById('parentDivId') gets a reference to the element with the specified ID, in this case a <div id="parentDivId">
- .getElementsByTagName('abbr')[0] finds all child elements within the div that are <abbr> tags, and returns them in an array. The [0] part gets this first element from the array.
- .getAttribute('data-utime') gets that attribute from the selected abbr element.

Is that clear?
See here for reference to the selectors you have available in vanilla javascript - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp. If you're using jquery (looks like this question is tagged that way) it has its own set of selectors with additional flexibility.